# join two tables that may contain no data

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

### attendance

- attendance_id_pk
- student_id
- is_excused

### checking

- checking_id_pk
- student_id
- parent_consent

---

I want to join all data in the attendance table to checking table IF:

is_excused = true and parent_consent = false using student_id. It is possible that attendance table has no data in it. How to do this in postgresql?

Comment: I'm lost. You want to join them when is_excused has a value yet it has no data? If is_excused has a value then it's not empty!

Comment: You want to join them? So JOIN them. What is the problem? Is your JOIN not working?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for, is a result set where records from `checking` table are shown even if there are no matching records in the `attendance` table. If that's the case, then you must use OUTER joins:

```
SELECT * FROM attendance RIGHT OUTER JOIN checking 
               ON (attendance.student_id = checking.student_id)
WHERE is_excused AND NOT parent_consent
```

Comment: let's say: attendance has two data in it and checking has 20 data in it. how to possilby join do this? or is it possible?

Comment: Yes, join is always possible. Depending on the values in the two tables, you might get 2 X 20 = 40 records, or no record at all, as the result of the join.  The result of join depends on the join type, the join condition, and the tables' values. If any of these are changed, you might get different result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM checking c
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON c.student_id = a.student_id AND a.is_excused = "true"
WHERE c.parent_consent = "false";
```

This will give you all the checking information where parent_consent is false, and whenever you have attendance information with is_excused = true.

If you don't want the information from checking when there is no information in attendance, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM checking c
INNER JOIN attendance a ON c.student_id = a.student_id 
WHERE c.parent_consent = "false"
AND a.is_excused = "true";
```

---

**EDIT:**

In the case you want not to JOIN but to get all the information from both tables, You can do:

```
SELECT checking_id_pk,student_id,parent_consent FROM checking c
WHERE c.parent_consent = "false"
UNION
SELECT attendance_id_pk,student_id,is_excused FROM attendance a
WHERE a.is_excused = "true";
```

See more information on UNION in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html):

> UNION effectively appends the result of query2 to the result of query1
>   (although there is no guarantee that this is the order in which the
>   rows are actually returned). Furthermore, it eliminates duplicate rows
>   from its result, in the same way as DISTINCT, unless UNION ALL is
>   used.

Comment: let's say: attendance has two data in it and checking has 20 data in it. how to possilby join do this? or is it possible?

Comment: See my edited query. I guess you want all the information, but not joined. The term you are using for JOIN is when you want to match information from one table to another.

Comment: I tried your example but I got an error. The error is "each UNION query must have the same number of columns"

Comment: You said your tables had 3 columns each. I'll update my query to name them

Comment: @xyxy. Was that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM checking c
LEFT JOIN attendance a ON c.student_id = a.student_id AND a.is_excused = "true"
WHERE c.parent_consent = "false"
```

Comment: let's say: attendance has two data in it and checking has 20  data in it. how to possilby join do this? or is it possible?